# Why isn't there an article after “comme” in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, articles

> Regarde le cahier que Than reçoit comme cadeau de sa copine.

I was wondering why there isn't an 'un' before the 'cadeau'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure [Circeus's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2369/79) (while valid) is enough to answer your question.
These two sentences are correct:

> Regarde le cahier que Than reçoit comme cadeau.
>   Regarde le cahier que Than reçoit comme un cadeau.

In the first one, the speaker adds the precision that he/she talks about the notebook which was offered **as** a gift. In the second sentence, Than receives a notebook and a precision is added that it looks **like** a gift, but maybe it isn't.

*Note:* With this simple construction, because the article disappears,  French is not able to make the difference beetween “as a gift” and the less common “as the gift”. One would need complex paraphrases to express the latest.

Comment: To further clarify, if an article (or any determiner, I think) is present, the meaning draws on the distinct function of *comme* as a conjunction expressing a comparison (in the first sentence, it's just one of several ways to express "as a gift").

Comment: Yes, the first sentence means "as a gift" where the second means "as if it were a gift" or "something like a gift".

Answer (score 13):

In French, it is very common for [predicatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_%28adjectival_or_nominal%29) (*attribut*) to lack articles (Grevisse §586 b), and indeed in this construction, called an *attribut du complément d'objet*, "cadeau" is a predicative to "cahier", which is why the article drops.

Comment: The reference to Grevisse here does not correspond to the relevant section in my edition (12th) where I think the relevant section is §570, 3

Comment: @TomAdair yeah mine is the 14th edition. We're both slightly outdated, though. The current edition is the 16th

Answer (score 3):

"Comme cadeau" translates as a gift.
"Comme un cadeau" translates as if it were a gift.

Ex: Cette année, sa mère offrit à Marie un ordinateur comme cadeau d'anniversaire. (This year, her mother gave Marie a computer as a birthday gift).

Ex: Marie accepta le manteau comme un cadeau de sa mère. (Marie took the coat as if it were a gift from her mother). (Her mother passed away and her father gave Marie his late wife's coat).